# R: How to group by a column and remove rows with repeats in another column for each group

Tags: r, unique

Having a data frame as below, I need to group by the data frame by "ID" and next remove the rows with repetitive value for column "course"?

```
    ID       time  course
1 ID01 01.10.2012    Math
2 ID01 10.11.2012    Math
3 ID01 01.01.2013    Math
4 ID01 01.01.2013 History
5 ID02 10.01.2013    Math
6 ID02 02.05.2013    Math
7 ID02 15.01.2013 History
```

I need to have this:

```
 1 ID01 01.10.2012    Math
 4 ID01 01.01.2013 History
 5 ID02 10.01.2013    Math
 7 ID02 15.01.2013 History

dput(test)
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ID01", 
"ID02"), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("01.10.2012", "10.11.2012", "01.01.2013", 
"10.01.2013", "02.05.2013", "15.01.2013"), class = "factor"), 
    course = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Math", 
    "History"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "time", 
"course"), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ff=your.table
ff[!duplicated(ff[c("ID","course")]),]
```